# Problem when compiling

Tags: thesis

i am trying to compile chapters of my **thesis** with texmaker. When i play F6 the console log file returns:

The log file is very large, i paste part of it:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.5.25)  26 MAY 2017 00:46
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**intro.tex
(./intro.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 5 languages loaded.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 L
     as computadoras han permitido la expansiÃ³n de diversos campos cientÃ­f...

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

Missing character: There is no L in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
```

Thank you for helping. Any advice will be welcome

Comment: It will list where the error is (line number). Please post the full log file. Also, don't use `\large`  in `\chapter ` that's a very bad idea.

Comment: I didn't face any error when compile your code, if possible, please post your .log file

Comment: @MadyYuvi i edited. Some other chaptes do not produce .log. I do not know why. But it would be a less important problem

Comment: Go to your main buffer and click on *Make this the master file* somewhere in the Texmaker interface. You can hit compile from your chapter files now as well.

Comment: @Johannes_B mm not sure if I understood. Do you mean that it is possible to compile from chapters (same operation that was done with F6 from main file) but setting the main as it file with *make this master file* option? Only to be sure.

Comment: Declaring the main file as master makes texmaker remember that it has to compile the master file, even if one of your chapter buffers is open. There really is no magic behind it, but reading an introduction to how LaTeX works might help you understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong file `intro.tex` is compiled. It starts with the text `Las computadoras`. Look for the file that starts with `\documentclass` and compile this file with LaTeX.